# How to avoid multiple dot in calculator in android studio

Tags: java, calculator, dot

[Here is my code for dot button. But i need to avoid multiple dot input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSOSi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean variable to control the number of dots you need. enabling or disabling that boolean variable will allow or disallow to enter dot.

e.g.

```
   _allowDots = true;
   if(_allowDots)
   {
      tvInput.setText(process + ".");
     _allowDots = false
   }
```

next time when it will run. it will not go inside of the statement.

Comment: Haider bro...it working only for one dot for one time...if i click dot for the first time i can't click it second timr...like i want that 1.2+1.3...but it just working for 1.2 either if i clear it totally dot Isn't working...

Comment: yes you have to assign true to _allowDots variable to get . next time in your example its a good idea to assign true to _allowDots in your process "+" code then after + you can get another dot for one time.